# Ubuntu upgrade fails due to missing packages. (Forbidden)

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I am trying to upgrade my 13.10 OS to the new 14.04 version.
This fails due to missing packages.

I tried multiple times.
Is the PNL mirror borked?

```
Failed to fetch http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/main/libl/liblog-message-simple-perl/liblog-message-simple-perl_0.10-1_all.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpod-latex-perl/libpod-latex-perl_0.61-1_all.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libterm-ui-perl/libterm-ui-perl_0.42-1_all.deb 403  Forbidden
```

Comment: Try another mirror ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open software & updates change download from others and select best server option after close and try to upgrade** not slove your problem!

- Change your server to main server[image]

after unselect non recommends repositories[image]

But don't unselect canonical partners and independent repositories[image]

after press

> alt+ctrl+t
>    for open your terminal and update repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Upgrade got progressed further now, but still woes. Now it wants to do a 'partial upgrade' instead, and although 'About' now lists 14.04 I think my computer is in a faulty state. My fuji camera is no longer found.